# Securing rest api with jwt

Tags: node.js, rest, api, token

I've been trying to secure my rest api with authentication so only trusted apps could consume this api. I've been looking for best practices and guides but none of them actually explains that in real-world example.

I created jsonwebtoken authentication similar to this:

```
if(!user){
    res.json({success:false, message: 'auth failed, user not found'});
} else {
    var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
        expiresIn: 1440 //24 hours
    });
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'token generated',
        token: token
    });
}
```

This works ok, returning a token which I can then pass with all requests to an api, but how do I make the app find that token and use it instead manually pass token every api call?

I've seen that in most of the time, you can generate special api-key within the app and include that info in client's app which works kind of like a token and there is no need to request new token from server.

How does that work or how do I create trusted apps keys for my restful service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JWT is perfectly fine, in fact I use it myself. But the way you're using it in your example is not very secure. JWTs are not encrypted, but rather just encoded. If you're sending this token to someone and including sensitive information such as `superSecret`, anybody with access to the token will be able to decode this.

A cleaner idea is to attach this token to a session object. If you're using Node.js and Express then you can use the `express-session` library. This attaches a session object to each request. Once a user is authenticated you can assign this token to the session object and store it either in a database or memory store such as `redis`. For an additional layer of security you can generate an `api-key` for each trusted app and store that in your database. The `api-key` can be passed through as a header.

To set up sessions with Express, but I do suggest you read up on other options and ways to configure this to your needs:

```
var session = require("express-session");
app.use(session({
        secret: /* Your secret. */,
        store: /* Your redis store object. */,
        client: /* Your redis client object. */,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

To attach the `access-token` to the user on login (for example):

```
router.post("/login", function(request, response){

    /* Do all user validation here */

    request.session.token = jwt.sign({
            /* User info to store in session. */
    }, "superSecret");

    return response.redirect( /* Dashboard */ );

});
```

The way you would authenticate a user then would be:

1. Validate that the `api-key` is valid.
2. Check `if(!user.session){ // Route to login page. }`
3. Check `if(!user.session.token){ // Not authorized. }`
4. Validate `user.session.token`
5. Using the credentials inside the token (do NOT put the users password in here), validate that the user is a valid user in your system - assuming that they have registered an account on your website/platform. You can for instance store permission levels and userIds with an email address or something that you would use for validation.

I hope this helps! It takes a while to wrap your head authentication practices.

Comment: yes this helped me a little bit. will try to make api authentication without user part so you can consume api within the app but every user of that app has access to it

Comment: Remember, that you'd want the user to be logged in before they access the API otherwise anybody on the outside would be able to use Postman for example and access the endpoints.

Comment: but why go for tokens if you store them on your serverside anyway? If you do so you could just stick with session cookies. And I am pretty sure you can decode the payload of your tokens but you cannot get 'supersecret' out of it.This is a great article to understand tokens better: https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/